# How to convert Jquery code to Javascript for GithubPages

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am new to javascript and still learning. I have an **svg map** of a country separated in regions, and I want to display some information when hovering over each region.

The code below is working fine (jquery) when running it locally but when uploading it to Github as a Github page it isn't working.

I would like some advice on how to transfom the below part of my code into javascript. (I have tried something with addEventListener and body.appendChild but with no success)

```
$('#regions > *').mouseover(function (e) {
    var region_data = $(this).data('region');

    // Info box informations
    $('<div class="info_box">' + region_data.region_name + '<br>' + '</div>').appendTo('body');
});

// Show info box when mousemove over a region
$('#regions > *').mousemove(function(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX, 
        mouseY = e.pageY;

    // Position of information box
    $('.info_box').css({
        top: mouseY-50,
        left: mouseX+10
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
   $('.info_box').remove();
});
```

I have tried something like the following :

```
var mapRegion = document.querySelectorAll("#regions > *");

    mapRegion.forEach(function(reg){
        
        reg.addEventListener('mouseover', function(el){  
            var perif_data = this.data('region');
            document.body.appendChild('<div class="info_box">' + region_data.region_name + '<br>' + '</div>');    
        }); 
        
        reg.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
            var mouseX = e.pageX; 
            var mouseY = e.pageY; 
            // Position of information box
            document.querySelector('info_box').style.top = mouseY-50;
            document.querySelector('info_box').style.css = mouseX+10;
        });
        
         reg.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
            reg.classList.remove('.info_box');
        });
        
    });
```

But I'm getting on console :

1. *this.data is not a function*
2. *document.querySelector(...) is null*

Comment: Well, you would probably need to add a `mouseover` listener to `#regions` and check the event's `currentTarget` to make sure it is a direct descendant. After you confirm that, you can then grab it's region data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern JavaScript makes this very easy. You just need to iterate over the results of the `querySelectorAll` call and add the listener to each child.

Also, it looks like your data is a JSON object, so you may need to parse it using `JSON.parse`.

I recommend not destroying and re-creating the infobox each time. Just update it with the latest info and hide/show it depending on whether or not your are currently mousing-over a region.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#regions > *')).forEach(region => {
  region.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    const infobox = document.querySelector('.info_box')
    const regionData = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.region)
    infobox.textContent = regionData.region_name
    infobox.classList.toggle('hidden', false)
  })
  region.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    const infobox = document.querySelector('.info_box')
    if (!infobox.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      Object.assign(infobox.style, {
        top: (e.pageY - 50) + 'px',
        left: (e.pageX + 10) + 'px'
      })
    }
  })
  region.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    const infobox = document.querySelector('.info_box')
    infobox.classList.toggle('hidden', true)
  })
})
```

```css
.info_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.info_box.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.region {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: thin solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="regions">
  <div class="region" data-region='{"region_name":"A"}'>Section A</div>
  <div class="region" data-region='{"region_name":"B"}'>Section B</div>
  <div class="region" data-region='{"region_name":"C"}'>Section C</div>
</div>

<div class="info_box hidden">
</div>
```

---

You can simply this by implementing an `addListeners` function that loops over all the elements and applies various event listeners.

```js
const addListeners = (selector, eventName, listener) => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach(el => {
    typeof eventName === 'string' && listener != null
      ? el.addEventListener(eventName, listener)
      : Object.keys(eventName).forEach(name =>
        el.addEventListener(name, eventName[name]))
  })
}

addListeners('#regions > *', {
  mouseover: e => {
    const infobox = document.querySelector('.info_box')
    const regionData = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.region)
    infobox.textContent = regionData.region_name
    infobox.classList.toggle('hidden', false)
  },
  mousemove: e => {
    const infobox = document.querySelector('.info_box')
    if (!infobox.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      Object.assign(infobox.style, {
        top: (e.pageY - 50) + 'px',
        left: (e.pageX + 10) + 'px'
      })
    }
  },
  mouseleave: e => {
    const infobox = document.querySelector('.info_box')
    infobox.classList.toggle('hidden', true)
  }
})
```

```css
.info_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.info_box.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.region {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: thin solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="regions">
  <div class="region" data-region='{"region_name":"A"}'>Section A</div>
  <div class="region" data-region='{"region_name":"B"}'>Section B</div>
  <div class="region" data-region='{"region_name":"C"}'>Section C</div>
</div>

<div class="info_box hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I'm gonna try this. Yes I'm using a json file which I'm loading from a Github repository with XMLHttpRequest(). At first I had getJSON but it isn't working on Github pages so i changed it.

Comment: @kostas_math I actually just simplified it. In my original response, I added the listeners to the region parent and checked if you were hovering over a direct descendant. That may be more preferred, if you have 100s or 1,000s of children. Because the amount of event handlers you have will scale multiplicativly.

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Im going to ''study'' it (because i don't have so much knowledge on javascript) just to understand everything.

Comment: So I'm gonna check this as the answer to my question.

Comment: @kostas_math Modern JS is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the body for Adding and removing the info_box
const body = document.querySelector("body");
//Get All Descendants of #Regions
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#regions > *");
//Create the info_box Element
const infoBoxElement = document.createElement("div");
//Set the class
infoBoxElement.className = "info_box";

//Iterate over each descendant of Regions
elements.forEach((element) => {
  //Let's add MouseOver Event
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    //get the "data-"" of the element and Parse it
    const regionData = JSON.parse(element.dataset.region);
    //Let's reuse the infoBoxElement and Assign the innerHTML
    infoBoxElement.innerHTML = regionData.region_name + "<br>";
    //Appending the infoBoxElement to the Body
    body.append(infoBoxElement);
  });

  //Let's add MouseMove Event
  element.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    const mouseX = e.pageX,
      mouseY = e.pageY;
    //Get the Infobox HTML element
    const infoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("info_box")[0];
    //Lets add the css Style
    infoBox.style.top = mouseX - 50;
    infoBox.style.top = mouseY + 10;
  });

  //Let's add MouseLeave Event
  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    //Get the Infobox HTML element
    const infoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("info_box")[0];
    //Lets get rid of it
    infoBox.remove();
  });
});
```